# multiple classes in single file in java

Tags: java

i new to  java, so this may sound a simple one but it still bothering me 
my code is as below:

```
public class guessgame {
    player p1;
    player p2;
    player p3;

    public void startgame() {
        p1 = new player();
        p2 = new player();
        p3 = new player();
        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;
        boolean p1isright = false;
        boolean p2isright = false;
        boolean p3isright = false;
        int targetnumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("i'm guessing a number between 0 and 9...");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("number to guess is " + targetnumber);
            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();
            guessp1 = p1.number;
            System.out.println("player one guessed " + guessp1);
            guessp2 = p2.number;
            System.out.println("player two guessed " + guessp2);
            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.println("player three guessed " + guessp3);
            if (guessp1 == targetnumber) {
                p1isright = true;
            }
            if (guessp2 == targetnumber) {
                p2isright = true;
            }
            if (guessp3 == targetnumber) {
                p3isright = true;
            }
            if (p1isright || p2isright || p3isright) {
                System.out.println("we have a winner ");
                System.out.println("player1 got it right.. ? " + p1isright);
                System.out.println("player2 got it right.. ? " + p2isright);
                System.out.println("player3  got it right.. ? " + p3isright);
                System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<GAME IS OVER>>>>>>>>>>");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("players will have to try again...!");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class player {
    int number = 0;

    public void guess() {
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println(" I'm guessing " + number);
    }
}

public class gamelauncher {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        guessgame game;
        game.startgame();
    }
}
```

i have included it in a single source file and named as gamelauncher.java
and i my errors are as follows as

```
game.java:1: error: class guessgame is public, should be declared in a file name
d guessgame.java
public class guessgame
       ^
game.java:59: error: class player is public, should be declared in a file named
player.java
public class player
       ^
game.java:68: error: class gamelauncher is public, should be declared in a file
named gamelauncher.java
public class gamelauncher
       ^
3 errors
```

then after googling it i realized that there should not more than one public class in single source file
my question is that

1. so do i have to part  my source file into three separate source files...?
2. so do i have to compile every class individually
3. is there a command line shortcut that can compile all classes
4. should i run all these classes by another special command line shortcut or is it is enough to run a class that contains main in case gamelauncher class

thanks in advance.....

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Eclipse, IntelliJ etc

Comment: Only a single class can be public if you want to define like that.

Comment: My personal two cents: start small. Don't write dozens/hundred lines of codes before running the compiler. Just write a few lines of which you think: "this is correct and should compile". Then run the compiler. Fix errors. Write a bit more code. Rerun the compiler. Then: stackoverflow doesn't exist to **teach** novice programmers. Meaning: **first** read books/tutorials (do the learning part), then start coding ... and then when you are really stuck; you are welcome to ask questions here. Anything else is a waste of your own time (and ours, too).

Comment: And another hint: please read the various "style guides" for java source code. Your way of naming classes and methods is "off standard"; and thereby only confusing the people you are asking for help.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. so do i have to part my source file into three separate source files...?

Yes, you have.<sup>1</sup> You could also work with *inner classes*, but for a beginner, regular classes in separate files are just fine.

> 2. so do i have to compile every class individually
> 3. is there a command line shortcut that can compile all classes

You can pass them all to `javac`, e. g. `javac guessgame.java player.java gamelauncher.java`, or use a wildcard, e. g. `javac *.java`. For bigger projects, you go best with an automated build system -- Make, Ant, Ivy, Maven ...

> 4. should i run all these classes by another special command line shortcut or is it is enough to run a class that contains main in case gamelauncher class

You should only run that class that contains the `main` method.

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out by @hexafraction, you could also just remove the `public` declaration and make the other two classes package-private. Yet this is absolutely unusual and I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: Remember that the OP can also declare these classes as package-private.

Comment: You don't have, create a file with the next classes class A{}

class B{}

class C{} name it as Dog.java and compile it using javac Dog,java and it is going to work, is not a good practice but it works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more than 1 class in same .java file, you have to make them inner classes, which means it should be within scope of the class on while java file is named.
Something like -

```
class A {
     class B{
     }
}
```

assuming your file is A.java

Comment: Non-static inner classes carry overhead that isn't always necessary. Additionally, they can't be constructed from a static context, and if A uses a lot of memory, just having a reference to B will keep a reference to A, meaning that the A instance will keep using memory, even if it is no longer necessary. If it is useful for organizational reasons to keep an inner class, and there is no requirement for it to have access to `A`'s state, then it would make more sense to declare it as `static class B`.

Comment: @hexafraction:  You're absolutely correct. But I answered just for how to keep multiple classes in same java file, irrespective of whether they are static or not. It was more about syntax than about best practices :)

Comment: However, your response *does* affect syntax slightly, or rather semantics. I can't just, in `main`, construct a `new B()`, which may affect the OP when they write further code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use all classes in same file then remove the `public` keyword from the class `guessgame` and `player`.

Your class file must have a name `gamelauncher.java` as `main` method resides in it.

**Warning:** Still you will definitely get `NullPointerException`, becase you declare

```
guessgame game;
```

but do not initialize it and try to access,

```
game.startgame();
```

which give you `NullPointerException`.

Try this:

```
guessgame game = new guessgame();
game.startgame();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in the next way, imagine that you have a file named **Dog.java** with the next content:

```
class A{}

class B{}

class C{}
```

As any of the classes is public you can compile it using javac Dog.java and it is going to work.

but if one of your classes is public the name of the file must be equals to the public class, eg if you modify the last example like this :
File `Dog.java`

```
public class A{}

class B{}

class C{}
```

And you try to compile It you are going to get "**class A is public, should be declared in a file named A.java**"

And for the last point you **can't** place all classes as public because only can have one public class per file.

1. so do i have to part my source file into three separate source files...? **you should but if you place all your classes in the same file it is going to work but only one must be public**
2. so do i have to compile every class individually **No you can comple your classes using the name of your file.java, if your file is named Hello.java you can compile it using javac Hello.java**
3. is there a command line shortcut that can compile all classes **yes is javac *.java**
4. should i run all these classes by another special command line shortcut or is it is enough to run a class that contains main in case gamelauncher class **You should only run that class that contains the main method.**